# How to manage a serial remote printer connection throught serial/network converter sw

Tags: sockets, printing, queue, buffer

**PREAMBLE**

My ticketing software is a web-based application that controls printers connected locally to its serial ports.
This software checks printer status before every ticket emission using a particular command and waits the printer status reply for few seconds, if the reply is negative or doesn't arrive means that the printer is not ready.

Obviously server is faster than the printer and an flow handshake is needed to avoid printer memory saturation, usually the standard RS232 hardware handshake is a good choice because it stops the server process waiting for printer free memory, therefore this can be consider a synchronous communication.

1. server sends a lot of data to the printer
2. the printer fills its memory and using its handshake stops the server
3. server stops the stream waiting for some free memory

**THE MAIN PROBLEM**

[image]

Sometimes I have to use remote clients over LAN but client's printer could not connected to the server with a serial cable, therefore I the only choice is to use a network socket connection. I have to use serial printers locally connected to the client by serial cable. In these cases I need a redirect software to create a network socket-tcp-listener to redirect data received from network to its serial port. This is the best one for me:
http://www.pira.cz/show.asp?art=piracom
The problem is that this connection is no longer synchronous:

1. server sends a lot of tickets over the network to the client server software and before every emission sends the status request to the printer and waits the reply
2. client receives data and redirect it to printer through serial port, when the printer memory is filled the client redirector starts to fill its buffer.
3. server doesn't know about this and continues to send data because its stream is not blocked... but it doesn't receive the status reply before a reasonable time because the command is not really sent to the printer but it is queued in the client buffer.

Is there any other solution to solve this problem with these conditions?

- I need to print to a remote printer throught a remote serial port (I cannot use an ethernet printer)
- Server should checks for printer status before each print

Comment: Hey! where's the code?

Comment: This is not a strictly code-related problem, I have to understand how to connect two devices. Should I ask it in another stack site?

Comment: Yes, I think it is: maybe http://serverfault.com/tour or http://superuser.com/tour will give you more answers :-)

Comment: Ok... I think I cannot get nothing from sysadmins about this problem, but I will try!